# LINQ query for Group by a key and then order by different column

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

i want to display countof  records based on grouping by the id and name then i want to order them in their descending order of display.

My database structure is as follows:-

```
rowid id    name         viewedon       viewedby
1     a1   reporter     23/07/2014      a@yahoo.com
2     a2   teacher      24/07/2014      test@gmail.com
3     a1   reporter     24/07/2014      wayne@zz.com
4     a2   teacher      24/07/2014      asdasd@zz.com
5     a1   reporter     24/07/2014      btttt@zz.com
6     a3   driver       26/02/2014      sfdf@yahoo.com 
7     a4   operator     3/3/1991        asds@asd.com  
8     a2   teacher      2/9/2011        tsdasd@gmail.com
9     a1   reporter     3/5/1992        asdas@fg.com
10    a4   operator     12/12/2005      asdss@a.com
11    a1   reporter     2/2/2002        as@as.com
12    a3   driver       10/7/2015       asdas@as.com
```

my Query is as follows

```
var q=from j in context.item 
       group jobs by new { j.Id, j.Name } into gr 
                                            select new DAO<String>
                                            {
                                                Key = gr.Key.Name,
                                                Count = gr.Count()                                   
                                            }).OrderByDescending(k => k.Count).Take(5).ToList();
```

This is giving correct result as follows:-

```
key           count 
reporter       5
teacher        3
operator       2
driver         2
```

reporter and teacher has high views so their count and order is justified .
now i have problem with this result. operator and driver has same view count but  since driver has latest viewon date  so it should come before driver.

so my result should be.

```
 reporter 5
 teacher  3
 driver   2
 operator 2
```

what should be my LINQ to achieve this result

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the column for ordering. You can try this way :

```
var q = (from j in context.item 
        group jobs by new { j.Id, j.Name } into gr 
        select new 
        {
            Key = gr.Key.Name,
            Count = gr.Count(),
            LastViewedOn = gr.Max(o => o.viewedon)
        }).OrderByDescending(k => k.Count).ThenByDescending(o => o.LastViewedOn)
          .Select(o => new DAO<String>
            {
                Key = o.Key,
                Count = o.Count                                   
            })
          .Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but still results are not showing according to requirement

Comment: Sure, I believe `ThenBy()` should've been `ThenByDescending()`. Could you try again?

Comment: yes i tried that too earlier but my prod database contains lot more realistic data so it was not working

Comment: Thanks for help. i need to change                                  LastViewedOn = gr.OrderByDescending(o => o.viewedon).FirstOrDefault()  to LastViewedOn=gr.Max(o=>o.viewedon)

Comment: Off course that will fix the code. I can see where it was doing wrong now. Thanks